# If a person is stubborn in his statement?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

When we ask a person (X) to change a method that he doing something regularly. He is not ready to accept our request and he says "I will do in the same way as I did previously" whether the method he doing is right or wrong.

I need some sentences How to we explain this situation to someone else "I explained him, but he(X) is rigid in his statement (or)

He (X) he is strong in his statement (or)

He is constantly holding his statement..... He is not ready to accept our request.

I'm not fluent in English now only learning to speak. So kindly  you yourself understand try to my question and give some proper sentences examples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _unyielding_ is frequently used to describe such people. _adamantine_ works well too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you really want to use the word *statement* in your explanation. In that case I would say:

> I have explained the matter to him, but he is ***stubbornly clinging to his statement***.

Stubbornly is defined by [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stubbornly) as meaning:

> in a way that shows you are determined to do what you want and refuse to do anything else.
>
> - The president *is stubbornly clinging to* policies that need changing.

However, there are plenty of other ways you could express someone's obstinacy. For example, [this related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224191/idiom-for-being-stubborn-about-an-opinion/224318) has among others

> He dug his heels in.

I also came across

> to have an ***anti-everything, nay-saying attitude*** ([lifehack](https://www.lifehack.org/articles/communication/12-ways-deal-with-stubborn-people-and-convince-them-listen.html) and [freedict](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/naysaying))

As an aside maybe only slightly related: As I was looking for other expressions I found the humorous:

> Mary Mary quite contrary, how does your garden grow (line from nursery rhyme).

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

- He is *pig-headed*.
- He is *obstinate*.
- He is *opinionated*.