# What do you call a person who's unwilling to grant some leeway to another one's position or argument?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, in an informal debate, one side will not grant or concede points to the other even in the face of evidence refuting their stated position. Is there a word to describe this attitude along the lines of "not being gracious?"

Comment: There's lots of words, stubborn, pig-headed, irrational, et. al. I don't think you've narrowed it down enough to get answers better than you could find with a thesaurus.

Comment: Related question about idioms: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/224191/191178

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for assuming I did not do that first before coming here.

Comment: @Laurel Thank you

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Comment: @tchrist well, maybe people are asking for "horrible things about something we disapprove of" (lol, presumptuous much?) because they're actually nice people who are not used to saying horrible things? What's rather funny is passive-aggressive people who prefer strawman arguments instead of engaging in a relevant discussion, who use the every opportunity to get on a soapbox to lecture and talk down to anybody posting here. To them, no one is asking innocently anymore, even if that's the actual case. The world is truly f**ked if these kinds of people comprise more than half of its inhabitants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like **Obstinate**' for this, it has negative connotations, and covers all of your request as in "stubbornly adhering to an opinion, purpose, or course in spite of reason, arguments, or persuasion'"[1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obstinate)