# English equivalent for the Chinese idiom 执迷不悟, to obstinately persist in going about things the wrong way

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

This means something along the lines of:

> To obstinately persist in going about things the wrong way.

This could be translated as just being stubborn but I don't think that's as poetic. Is there a more idiomatic way of saying so?

Comment: Are these the answers you're looking for? [Idiom for being stubborn about an opinion](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/224191/191178)

Comment: Most suggestions seem to focus more on ***refusing to be be persuaded** [to change current behaviour]*, but for an expression more explicitly referring to *current behaviour having a negative rather than positive effect*, there's ***beating one's head against a brick wall***.

Answer (score 1):

Although not exact equivalents, the following words and phrases convey the idea of (negative) persistence:

- [Deaf to reason](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/deaf%20to%20reason): "*sticking to an opinion, purpose, or course of action in spite of reason, arguments, or persuasion*"
- [Pigheaded](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pigheaded): "*willfully or perversely unyielding, obstinate*". Also [bullheaded](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/bullheaded) and [wrongheaded](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/wrongheaded).
- [Pertinacious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pertinacious): "*adhering resolutely to an opinion, purpose, or design. Perversely persistent. Stubbornly tenacious*"

Depending on the context, you can also use [dig one's heels in](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/to-dig-ones-heels-in), [hell-bent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/hell-bent) or [dogged](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dogged).

Answer (score 0):

Does Albert Einstein's "**definition of insanity**" sound familiar? It is a popular quote: [definition of insanity](https://hashimashi.com/albert-einsteins-definition-of-insanity/?nowprocket=1#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CInsanity%20is%20doing%20the%20same%20thing%20over%20and,with%20overweight%20is%20guilty%20by%20reason%20of%20insanity.) Idiomatic - yes, Poetic - maybe not so much.

> Einstein’s classic definition of insanity is “***doing the same thing
> over and over again and expecting different results.***” This famous
> quote is attributed to Albert Einstein though there is evidence that
> it first appeared in a Narcotics Anonymous publication in 1981 as
> “Insanity is repeating the same mistakes and expecting different
> results.”

Answer (score 0):

There's a phrase that describes an idea that someone is obsessed with, beyond all reason, to the extent that it is a psychological problem:  [***Idée fixe***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id%C3%A9e_fixe_(psychology)).  The phrase is French in origin;  in that language, it literally means "fixed idea".

> An idée fixe is a preoccupation of mind believed to be firmly resistant to any attempt to modify it, a fixation. ... Although the afflicted person can think, reason and act like other people, they are unable to stop a particular train of thought or action.

An example taken from the above-linked Wikipedia article is taken from a book about the early-2000s War on Terror:

> Iraq was portrayed as the most dangerous thing in national security. It was an **idée fixe**, a rigid belief, received wisdom, a decision already made and one that no fact or event could derail.